# How to find data about earning per share of S&P 500

Tags: data-request, stock-market

I am working on a small project regarding PE ratio of SP500,for which I need historic earning per share data of SP500. I searched finance yahoo, but it has only prices data. Could anyone tell me the website where one can obtain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=S%26P+500+p%2Fe+ratio) turns up sites like

- http://www.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3021-peyield.html
- http://www.multpl.com/table?f=m
- https://www.macrotrends.net/2577/sp-500-pe-ratio-price-to-earnings-chart
- https://ycharts.com/indicators/sp_500_pe_ratio

which slightly disagree about whether the current trailing ratio is just above or just below 20